# I got 3 tables and I need some query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I got 3 tables in my database:

Authors:
id | first_name | last_name

Books:
id | title | genre

and a table with a book-author relationship, where one book can have multiple authors:

book_id | author_id

```
    1 | 1
    1 | 2
    1 | 3
    1 | 4
    2 | 5
    2 | 6
    3 | 7
```

here is an example:

I need to get a table like this:

book_id | title | genre;

where number of authors more than 2 and filter by some genre.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: This feels like a homework question. Please show us what you've tried so we can help guide from that starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm new to sql and don't even know where to start. I can make a filter by genre, and by the number of authors, but for this I need to get a table with the number of authors and how to do it I do not know.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Insert images/links using edit functions. Also, links die. Make your post self-contained. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS Please use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly say what you mean.

Comment: When this is clear, your goal and/or its parts will be faqs. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly. Googling 'site:stackoverflow.com sql rows with columns that appear (n or more OR at least n) times in a table'--my 1st hit is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check the below script:

```
select t.book_id,t.title,t.genre from 
(select ba.book_id,count(distinct ba.author_id) as results,b.title,b.genre from #books b join #book_author ba on b.id=ba.book_id
--where b.genre='tech' -- comment this if genre filter not needed
group by ba.book_id,b.title,b.genre
having count(distinct ba.author_id)>1) t
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Unclear questions should be commented on asking for clarity & closed until clear, not "answered" by a guess. If you don't have enough reputation, just wait. Moreover, when clear this will likely be an obvious duplicate, which should also be closed and not answered.